# How do I remove grub rescue from second hdd without reformatting?

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, easybcd

I have googled and all the answers are to format the drive. **I can't format this drive** because there is too much data on it for me to backup. I do have it set as the last boot entry in the bios but unfortunately my bios has...issues and sometimes doesn't detect any other HDD.

When this happens, it uses the secondary and goes to grub rescue saying no bootable device found. Then I have to physically remove the drive since the bios no longer gives boot or bios options after grub rescue enters the picture (even removing the battery doesn't.

I tried easybcd but it only wants to modify my primary drive. I couldn't find an option to change the drive its looking at. **The secondary, grub infested, drive is just one NTFS partition.**

I can't believe I can't find a tool that does this. Its just low level disk manipulation. Am I missing something? Primary drive is windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Boot a Linux live image, install syslinux from its repo (or pick one that already has syslinux installed), and use `dd` to write `/usr/share/syslinux/gptmbr.bin` to the appropriate hard drive.

```
sudo dd if=/usr/share/syslinux/gptmbr.bin of=/dev/sdX
```

[Further details about gptmbr.bin et alia](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mbr)

Comment: So I read the link but im not clear what it does. To be clear, without the second drive windows boots perfectly. The second drive doesn't need a MBR at all right? Wouldn't I want to erase the MBR from the secondary, not write one?

Comment: @FrostyFire: You can't "remove" a MBR, you can only replace it with something else.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. That makes sense. Do you know a distro that has syslinux already installed, off the top of your head?

Comment: [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) seems to [have it](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/packages.html), but I don't know if the version is recent enough.

Comment: Thanks I'll mark this as the answer if no one can tell me a windows tool. (dont have a spare flashdrive or DVD)

Comment: You could try Rawrite, but it's a little more cumbersome doing it under Windows instead.

Comment: There should also conceivably be a way to boot DSL from one of the EFI partitions, but I couldn't tell you how.